# Running a program in multiple subdirectories simultaneously

Tags: linux, file-permissions

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605106/copying-files-in-multiple-subdirectories-in-the-linux-command-line)
 of performing commands in multiple subdirectories simultaneously.

I'd like to run a program I've copied into every subdirectory which takes `*.in` files in the current directory as input files. I can `find` the program, but how do I tell it to run when I've found it?

Answer (score 1):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ for program in $(find . -name $PROGRAM); do
 (cd $(dirname $program) && ./$(basename $program));
done
```

where `PROGRAM` is the name of your program.